# How to convert SparseToDense's to Tensor or int array?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-android, ctc

I have implemented LSTM-CTC model in android device and comes to this code block.

```
SparseToDense sparseDense = ctc_decode(out, input_length, true, beam_width, top_paths);
```

I am getting the sparseDense object perfectly with expected shape but i don't know how to get retrieve float array from this.

If anyone know, please reply...

Thanks.

Comment: What are you asking? You get the dense array from the sparse then you're trying to convert the tensor into floating values to be used?

Comment: ** session.runner().fetch(sparseToDense.asOutput()).run() ** were throwing INT64 Sparse OPKernel error, but after converting all the parameters of the SparseToDense to the INT32, it get resolved. However now i worry about the accuracy mismatch in android devices due to this casting.

Comment: Please update the question with more relevant information and the actual error messages

Answer (score 0):

** session.runner().fetch(sparseToDense.asOutput()).run() ** were throwing INT64 Sparse OPKernel error, but after converting all the parameters of the SparseToDense to the INT32, it get resolved.